# Increasing precision of odeint

Tags: python-3.x, precision, ode

I'm solving four coupled ODEs in Python 3 using odeint to get N1[x], Ntau[x], Nmu[x] and Ne[x]. I solve them between 0.1 and 8 on the x-axis and in the end I am interested only in the value Ntau[8]+Nmu[x]+Ne[x].

Unfortunately, some of these functions are of order +/-10000 whilst the sum comes to 1e-14 typically. This means that the sum evaluated at x=8 is dominated by numerical errors.

My implementation is rather complicated and involves lots of irrelevant details so I won't share it here (unless it is requested) but rather ask for general advice.

Comment: This problem (and its presumed solution) have little to nothing to do with programming and thus I would consider this question off-topic here. It is however well-suited for [scicomp.se].